# Does copy and paste fonts effect file paths?

Tags: windows, directory, nwjs

When i use https://www.fontcopypaste.com/ to change a font like this " " how does it actually affect the letters? I'm trying to name an external drive like that, and it appears to make my path in my program I'm making on that drive not work. Same thing with folder I've named like that. In my program my path might be c:\SECURE DRIVE\DOCUMENTS but it doesn't work. I even tried c:\ \ｄｏｃｕｍｅｎｔｓ\ With the same font i used on the actual drive and folder and it still doesn't work. How can I make this work or something like it?

EDIT:

This is what happens when I change the folder name with a copy and paste font. The paths in my code dont recognize it anymore.

[image]

VS CODE has a tooltip that says character U+1d411 "R" could be confused with U+0052 "R" because similarities in code.

Comment: What does the `nwjs` tag mean here?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: \ is the path separator on Windows, not /. Don't make the problem more complicated by having to rule out incorrect / usage.

Comment: The `nwjs` tag is invalid for this post. This has absolutely nothing to do with NW.js.

Comment: I mean the application is a nwjs application i figured there might be some specific interworking's related to it

Comment: I have run into several problems that are very nwjs specific and had to do with the way it processes and handles code.

Answer (score 1):

File paths don't use fonts and you are not really copying a font, you are copying text that uses various Unicode [codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) to emulate funny fonts.

These paths should work fine if you are using the Unicode functions like `CreateFileW` or `_wfopen`.

If you are using `CreateFileA`, `fopen` or `std::string` you are going to run into codepage conversion issues. This applies to any framework and 3rd-party code you might be using.

Some of these codepoints might be outside the basic multilingual  plane (BMP) and will require correct handling of surrogate pairs when dealing with UTF-16LE.

Comment: In my code, should I use the same copy and paste font or just use the normal plain text format?

Comment: They are not fonts. You need to copy the string from the website into your code, assuming your language supports Unicode.

Comment: Check my edits @Anders